# MVC Display Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Following this MVC Tutorial, but cannot get the display customer view to display after input the data.  I don't see anything I do wrong

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207797/Learn-MVC-Model-View-Controller-step-by-step-in-7

here is my fill customer

```
<div>
          <form action="DisplayCustomer.aspx" method="post">
            Enter Customer Code: <input type="text" name="CustomerCode" /><br />
            Enter Customer Name: <input type="text" name="CustomerName" /><br />
            Ennter Customer Amout: <input type="text" name="CustomerAmount" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit customer data" />
          </form>
    </div>
```

here is my display customer

```
public ActionResult DisplayCustomer()
        {
            Customer localCustomer = new Customer();
            localCustomer.Code = Request.Form["CustomerCode"].ToString();
            localCustomer.Name = Request.Form["CustomerName"].ToString();
            localCustomer.Amount = Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["CustomerAmount"].ToString());

            return View(localCustomer);
        }
```

then

```
<div>
        The name of the customer is: <%:Model.Name = "test" %>
        <br />
         The code of the customer is: <%:Model.Code %>
         <br />
          The amout refund to the customer is: <%:Model.Amount%>
    </div>
```

seems like something is wrong with the steps

I got this error when I tried

### Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /customer/DisplayCustomer.aspx

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

Answer (score 0):

The correct path for the request is `/customer/displaycustomer`

The `.aspx` extension gets handled in a different way, so the MVC Routing Engine is never fired, and as that page doesn't exist at that path the result is a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to remove **.aspx** extension. Just request the page as /Customer/DisplayCustomer.

As a side note, you may need to update your form aswell and remove the aspx extension, eg:

```
<form action="DisplayCustomer" method="post">
Enter customer id :- <input type="text" name="Id" /> <br />
Enter customer code :- <input type="text" name="CustomerCode" /><br />
Enter customer Amount :-<input type="text" name="Amount" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit customer data" />
</form>
```

replaced the line:

```
<form action="DisplayCustomer.aspx" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="DisplayCustomer" method="post">
```

Comment: Works fine now. Why when i remove the .aspx visual studio shows that file was not found.